# Prove that $\overrightarrow{AQ}=\overrightarrow{BQ}$ $\implies$ $A=B$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Prove that $\overrightarrow{AQ}=\overrightarrow{BQ}$ $\implies$ $A=B$.

My doubt is whether it is a question that must be solved by algebraism or just by definitions...

Comment: @DietrichBurde A, B and Q are points

Comment: Points in $\Bbb R^n$? Then we may assume $Q=0$ and $A=\overrightarrow{AQ}=\overrightarrow{BQ}=B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\overrightarrow{AQ}=\overrightarrow{BQ}\implies \overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{BQ}-\overrightarrow{AQ}=0$$
and $$\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{OB}-\overrightarrow{OA}=0$$
$$\implies\overrightarrow{OA}=\overrightarrow{OB}\implies A=B$$

Comment: If $\overrightarrow{OA}=\overrightarrow{OB}$ proves that $A=B$, then why doesn't $\overrightarrow{AQ}=\overrightarrow{BQ}$ prove it by itself?

Comment: $O$ is the origin, relative to which all points are defined, but $Q$ is not

Comment: But the point $Q$, although not an origin, is still sufficient to be the same definite point for both vectors $\overrightarrow{AQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{BQ}$, and so the vectors being equal, shouldn't that be reason to say that $A=B$?

Comment: If that is the case then there is nothing to prove